# How can I connect two plumbing vents in a horizontal run?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

I have a vertical vent coming into my basement and I need it to go to a horizontal vent on both sides.  for the life of me I am not able to find any kind of vent Tee where its straight up and down without one side having a curve.  If I use something like a sanitary tee (which has a curve) am I going to restrict air flow on one of the horizontal pipes (mainly the one not on the curve) I am able to find cleanouts and converters to change the threaded top to a glue able kind (would that be ok?) or should I just put a y on the vertical for one direction and a 90 at the bottom for the other horizontal direction?

The venting is for the drainage, not the HVAC.  Something like this
https://www.lowes.com/pd/NIBCO-1-1-2-in-dia-ABS-Vent-Tee-Fitting/1000221855

Comment: The way I read this, you are looking for a cross; is that correct?

Comment: It sounds like you need to join two vents in a horizontal run. Your description is a bit confusing (and your tags were misleading). Please revise to explain more carefully what the overall project is, and add photos or a sketch if you can. Thanks.

Comment: How about making a sketch of what you're after (doesn't have to be fancy or to scale, write dimensions on it if they'll be helpful/important)? Or, if the walls are open, take a picture and draw some arrows on it. You can then post the pic ([edit] it into your question), and everyone will have a _much_ better idea of what you're after...

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please consider [registering](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and most importantly [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers). Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

The product you want is called a **Vent Tee** and they are made in PVC.  If they're not stocked at your local home improvement stores, check a specialty supplier (locally or online) and you'll definitely find them.

Keep in mind the vent needs to be able to drain water (condensation, rain, etc.)  Horizontal vent runs should follow the related minimum slope requirement -- usually 1/4-inch per foot, like drains.